# Synfusion Pie-Chart only displays y-values. How can I add the x-values as Labels?

Tags: c#, charts, console-application, syncfusion

I am currently working on an C# console-application that creates and saves various charts as images using the Syncfusion library (v20.4.0.53).

So far everything worked fine and I am almost finished. Unforutately I am running into an issue with the pie chart type. I want all x-values (string) of the ChartSeries to be displayed as text in the chart and all y-values (int) to be displayed in the legend, in the top right corner but I am not able to get this working. Only the numeric values are displayed in both places.

```cs
// Create Chart-Control
ChartControl chart = new ChartControl();
chart.Series.Clear();
chart.Size = new Size( 1920, 950 );

// Create Chart-Series
ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries("ExampleChart", ChartSeriesType.Pie);

series.Points.Add( "Value 1", 25 );
series.Points.Add( "Value 2", 75 );

// Add Chart-Series to Chart-Control
chart.Series.Add( series );
chart.Series[0].Style.DisplayText = true;

// Save Chart to image
chart.SaveImage( "image.png" );
```

I already researched a lot and have tried different solutions, e.g. to set `ShowDataPointLabels = true`. In the [official documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/chart/chart-series#showdatabindlabels) the diagram looks like this:[image: x-Values are "in" the Chart, y-Values are in the Legend]

However, mine looks like this:
[image: "Value 1" and "Value 2" should be displayed "in" the chart and "25" and "75" in the legend]

I also tried to create a new `ChartLegend` and adding it manually to the `ChartSeries`, but I don't manage to add multiple `ChartLegendItem` objects.

Do any of you maybe have an idea how I can solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The X values in data labels using the Style. Text property has been displayed. The following are the code snippet and images.

```
ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries("ExampleChart", ChartSeriesType.Pie);



        series.Points.Add("Value 1", 25);

        series.Points.Add("Value 2", 75);

        series.Points.Add("Value 3", 50);

        series.Points.Add("Value 4", 45);

       

        chart.Series.Add(series);

        chart.Series[0].Style.DisplayText = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < series.Points.Count; i++)

        {

            series.Styles[i].Text = series.Points[i].Category;

        }
```

[image: PieChart Output]